# GridView, RowEditing, How to change text in textbox when editing row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I`m working with GridView. I have a problem with the change of value in textbox (t5 and t6) during the editing row.
I want after pressing the edit button in TextBox(t5 and t6) were only the first 10 characters (yyyy-mm-dd). Paste the code below.

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        Label350.Text = string.Empty;

        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex];

        GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = true;
        GridView1.Columns[8].Visible = true;
        GridView1.DataSourceID = "";
        GridView1.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[8].Visible = false;


        TextBox t5 = row.FindControl("TextBox5") as TextBox;
        TextBox t6 = row.FindControl("TextBox6") as TextBox;

        if (t5.Text.Length > 11)
        {
            string v = t5.Text;
            v.Substring(0, 10);
            t5.Text = v;
        }

        if (t6.Text.Length > 11)
        {
            string v2 = t6.Text;
            v2.Substring(0, 10);
            t6.Text = v2;
        }
    }
```

Error message when I click the edit button.

> „Object reference not set to an instance of an object”

Need help!.

Comment: and if you debug, at which line do you have the error? can you show the markup of your EditTemplate and the binding please?

Comment: I have error in line:  if (t5.Text.Length > 11)